# AWS EC2 Windows Server 2022 instance trying to install git using AWS SM console

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-ec2, aws-ssm

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.37.1.windows.1/Git-2.37.1-64-bit.exe -UseBasicParsing -OutFile git-setup.exe
Start-Process .\git-setup.exe -Wait -ArgumentList '/VERYSILENT /NORESTART /NOCANCEL /SP- /CLOSEAPPLICATIONS /RESTARTAPPLICATIONS /COMPONENTS="icons,ext\reg\shellhere,assoc,assoc_sh" /LOG="C:\git-for-windows.log"'
```

I tried this script by RDP into EC2 instance and ran the script inside using the local PowerShell console then it worked.

But tried on the AWS Session Manager Console then it hung nothing happened for a long time.

Comment: Session Manager works by running an Agent installed on the instance. It 'pretends' to be a command-line but is actually running commands individually. It looks like whatever is running in `git-setup` is breaking the Session Manager session. You might need to run such a script via the [AWS Systems Manager Run Command - AWS Systems Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/run-command.html), which doesn't attempt to provide an 'interactive' session.